# MSSQL query: how to find the incorrect row by each partition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find incorrect rows according to the logic.

The logic is:

1. If the child has the row *(I will call first row)*

   ```
   | merit     | fruit | vegetable |
   | --------- | ----- | --------- |
   | behaviour | apple | cucumber  |
   ```

   then in the row with **merit = poem** and **fruit = apple** must be *only* **vegetable = cucumber** (cucumber and no other words)
   *(It is the second row)*

   ```
   | merit | fruit | vegetable |
   | ----- | ----- | --------- |
   | poem  | apple | cucumber  |
   ```
2. AND time interval of the second row must be 4 hours earlier or later from the time of the first row, as a correct example:

   ```
   | child_id  | date            | merit     | fruit | vegetable |
   | --------- | --------------- | --------- | ----- | --------- |
   | 2         | 1/26/2022 16:00 | poem      | apple | cucumber  |
   | 2         | 1/26/2022 18:00 | behaviour | apple | cucumber  |
   ```

   As we can see, it is in 4 hours interval

I have the table:

```
| child_id  | date            | merit       | fruit   | vegetable |
| --------- | --------------- | ----------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1         | 1/27/2022 14:00 | behaviour   | apple   | cucumber  |
| 1         | 1/27/2022 15:00 | poem        | apple   | carrot    |
| 1         | 1/27/2022 17:00 | sleep       | apple   | ginger    |
| 1         | 1/27/2022 20:00 | competition | berry   | tomatoe   |
| 2         | 1/26/2022 13:00 | sleep       | apricot | tomatoe   |
| 2         | 1/30/2022 13:00 | poem        | apple   | cucumber  |
| 2         | 1/29/2022 13:00 | poem        | apple   | cucumber  |
| 2         | 1/26/2022 16:00 | poem        | apple   | cucumber  |
| 2         | 1/26/2022 18:00 | behaviour   | apple   | cucumber  |
| 2         | 1/26/2022 19:00 | present     | apple   | broccoli  |
| 3         | 1/25/2022 11:00 | present     | orange  | cucumber  |
| 3         | 1/25/2022 13:00 | poem        | apple   | ginger    |
| 3         | 1/25/2022 15:00 | behaviour   | apple   | cucumber  |
| 4         | 1/26/2022 14:00 | behaviour   | apple   | cucumber  |
| 4         | 1/27/2022 21:00 | poem        | apple   | carrot    |
| 4         | 1/27/2022 15:00 | poem        | apple   | carrot    |
| 4         | 1/27/2022 20:00 | sleep       | apple   | ginger    |
| 4         | 1/27/2022 21:00 | competition | berry   | tomatoe   |
```

And the result I expect:

```
| child_id  | date             | merit | fruit | vegetable |
| --------- | --------------- | ----- | ----- | --------- |
| 1         | 1/27/2022 15:00 | poem  | apple | carrot    |
| 3         | 1/25/2022 13:00 | poem  | apple | ginger    |
```

I do not know how to find this rows by child. I wrote this SQL and stuck:

```sql
select * from example_1 where merit in ('behaviour', 'poem')
```

Do I need partitions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution is joining the table to itself using a LEFT OUTER JOIN and then only accepting records where the joined version of the table returns null:

```
SELECT e1.* 
FROM example_1 e1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN example_1 e2
       ON e1.fruit = e2.fruit
       AND e1.vegetable <> e2.vegetable
       AND e2.date BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -4, e1.date) AND e1.date
       AND e2.merit = 'behavior'
WHERE e1.merit = 'poem'
   AND e2.child_id IS NULL
```

The trick is mostly in the join criteria where we want to ensure we match `vegetable` between the 'behavior' and 'poem' while also checking for the last 4 hours.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didnt think that where we can use left join here

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN can be useful when we need to find records in one table that don't exist in another. Or... in this case in the same table. xQbert's answer using Correlated Subquery uses similar logic where the join criteria is in the subquery's WHERE clause. The benefit with the correlated subquery is that none of the records in the LEFTmost table (or subquery) are brought through to the select. We accomplish the same thing in my example by only selecting from the rightmost table. This is one of those fun queries in that there are multiple ways to solve it :)

Comment: @jnevill,  take the DB Fiddle I created and try this out.  I'm not getting what I'd expect to see.; but I know the concept is sound.  behaviour vs behavior is one thing: but I see a child ID of 4 in the results when I wouldn't expect it. and 3 seems to be missing.   *shrug* concept's sound

Comment: @xQbert I think I took a step back from the literal 'cucumber' and did the join between `poem` and `behavior`. So the `poem` records with `carrot` vegetable` are bringing through `2` and `4` `behavior` into the result set. I think my join is fancier than it needs to be if it's literally non-`cucumber` record.

Answer (score 1):

In this approach we use a collated subquery.  The top query B defines non-join limits of the data for the desired results.  So vegetable <> cucumber and merit =poem

The Exists ensures the limits of the first row are defined and the correlation for the non matches exists. so we ensure fruits match, merit is 'behavior', the child_id's match, and the difference in date is within 4 hours either way.

[DEMO-DB Fiddle UK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=89200b5d223f4ad0c3155985cf5f59ad)

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM table B
WHERE vegetable <> 'cucumber'
  and merit = 'poem'
  and exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM Table A
              WHERE A.Fruit = B.Fruit
                AND A.Child_id = B.Child_ID
                AND A.merit = 'behaviour' 
                AND abs(Datediff(hour,A.Date,B.Date)) <=4)
```

Giving us:

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----------+
| child_id |          date           | merit | fruit | vegetable |
+----------+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----------+
|        1 | 2022-01-27 15:00:00.000 | poem  | apple | carrot    |
|        3 | 2022-01-25 13:00:00.000 | poem  | apple | ginger    |
+----------+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for another approach